# Scrolling more than one page in a UIPageViewController creates white flash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

So I've created a UIPageViewController that works like I want it to except for one thing. If I swipe my finger very fast across the screen, the page scrolls one position to either side, then bounces and displays 3/4th cm of the next page after that again. Like so:

**Page zero** || **(current)Page one** --> Scroll to **Page two** -->Get a glimpse of **page three**

However, page three isn't loaded yet, because this function only preloads one ViewController at both sides of the current one, and not two, so in my example, it'll preload page zero and two, but not three, hence creating a white glimpse until I intent to scroll there from page two.

Methods preloading the surrounding pages:

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
 viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
  viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

How can I fix this??

**EDIT:**

I declare my ViewControllers in the UIPageViewController like this:

```
NSMutableArray *_viewControllers;
```

Then I populate the array like this:

```
_viewControllers = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (MyModel *currentObject in _myObjects)
{
    MyViewController *page = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerID"];
    // setup page with variables
    [_viewControllers addObject:page]; // add the page to the viewControllers array

}
```

Then these are the delegate methods:

```
-(UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
return _viewControllers[index];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
 viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger currentIndex = [_viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
if (currentIndex > 0) { currentIndex--; } else { currentIndex = ([_viewControllers count] - 1); }

return [_viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
  viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
NSUInteger currentIndex = [_viewControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
if (currentIndex < ([_viewControllers count] - 1)) { currentIndex++; } else { currentIndex = 0; }

return [_viewControllers objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
}

-(NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
return _viewControllers.count;
}

-(NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
{
return 0;
}
```

`MyModel` is just a class I built to populate the ViewControllers with data

Thank you!

Comment: Some actual code will help us identify the problem.

Comment: @Tander please see updated question

Comment: have you set transition style to scroll?

Comment: @tikider I have, yes

Comment: where do you use -(UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index; it is not required by the delegate

Comment: I followed a kind-of tutorial to create a UIPageViewController, but I'll remove it and try without it

Comment: @tikider same result :/

Comment: you should use the debugger and check the content of _viewControllers and the object that is returned from the two delegate methods and how many time they are called when you scroll; most of the time this will be enough to spot the problem.

Comment: @tikidir I did, it seems the functions are called just like they should and they return exactly what they sould

Comment: If I were you I would start a new minimal Xcode project and only write code to make this functionality work. This way you isolate your problematic feature and eliminate any potential interference by uncounted for parameters; then migrate the code to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to implement your own pageViewController with a custom cache. But to avoid the user to see the white glimpse, you can disable user interaction during transition:

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers{
    [pageViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed{
    [pageViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a similar problem. If you are using Interface Builder make sure the checkbox of "Clip Subviews" is checked for the view of the UIViewController (or subclass) you gave the id `@"MyViewControllerID"` .

Or just:

```
_viewControllers = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (MyModel *currentObject in _myObjects)
{
    MyViewController *page = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerID"];
    // Clip this view's overflowing subviews
    page.view.clipsToBounds = YES;
    // setup page with variables
    [_viewControllers addObject:page]; // add the page to the viewControllers array

}
```